# How do I determine why a webservice reference is being prevented from being added to my project in VS2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, web-services, visual-studio-2005, upgrade

I have a VS2005 project that contains a couple web service references. The project has recently been upgraded to VS2008 but now there is a problem with the web references...probably because they may not have been upgraded properly.

When I select Update Web Reference I get the following error:

"Value cannot be null. Parameter name: discoveryError % mexError" which is very helpful.

I've then deleted the web reference with the intent of re-adding it...

The Add Web Reference dialog comes up and successfully loads information about each of the methods associated with the web service.

However, I can't add the reference as the button to do so is grayed out and there is a text box titled "Web services found at this URL:" which contains the text "Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object".

Now finally, this brings me to my main question... How then do I add this web reference? Or better yet, how do I find out what is invalid about the "current state of the object"?

Has anyone had a similar experience in VS2008?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally figured it out.

I used [WebService Studio](http://www.codeplex.com/WebserviceStudio) to give me a better idea of what was going on. It came back with the error message "The request failed with HTTP status 407: Proxy Authentication Required".... which let me know that I had to install the new security certificate...the old one had expired.

I guess that answers this question about how to find more about what is invalid about the web service.

Comment: In my case was the VPN. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue on VS2010. In my case the problem was the proxy server. I got the wsdl from an external url. My solution: set the proxy in VS2010. Edit devenv.exe.config and add `<defaultProxy>` under `<system.net>`:

```
<system.net>
        <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true">
            <proxy bypassonlocal="True" proxyaddress="http://yourproxyserver:port"/>
        </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

If the proxy comes from a .pac file, you can omit the `<proxy>` tag:

```
   <system.net>
        <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true">
        </defaultProxy>
   </system.net>
```

An old post about a related issue:
http://fhtino.blogspot.it/2006/11/visual-studio-2005-proxy-problem-in-add.html

Answer (score 0):

I've  gotten the same error: with update reference from Visual Studio 2008

```
"Value cannot be null. Parameter name: discoveryError % mexError
```

I've already fixed it checking the project's folder ACL list.
Definitely, I needed to add IUSR to the folder's security... and that's it!

I worked for me, and I hope to help anyone as well...

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what was causing this error for me.  I could not add a Web Reference to a service, but I could add a service reference.  Unfortunately, I needed the Web Reference.

So what I did was download the WSDL to my machine.  When VS 2012 asks for the reference URL, I entered the path on my machine to the WSDL file.  That created the Web Reference for me.

Then I went into the reference.map and changed the location of the WSDL from the local path to the URL.  I haven't tried it out yet, but I'm thinking it should work...   At least I got my web reference created.

Answer (score 0):

Someone had fiddled with my IIS. Anonymous authentication was disabled for the service, once it was re-enabled this error message went away.